# How to read a file with multiple lines of both floats and integers in C?

Tags: c, file

Yeah, so I'm having difficulty trying to read a file with multiple lines of just numbers (a mix of floats and integers on each line).  I have a .txt file, and from there I'm trying to scan those lines, and identify if the second float is bigger than the first float, and make a decision based on the result.  So far, it works, but the problem is that I am not able to get to the second or third line, as the program just stops after the first line.

Here's a sample of the .txt file:

```
 9.64 6.30 3
 2.77 3.98 10
 5.63 4.20 5
 0.00 0.00 0
```

*When the scanf hits 0 for all values, it breaks out of the loops and stops the program.  Also, I don't necessarily know how many lines there are in the file, but I do know that for every line there will be two floats and 1 integer (in that order).

Now with these numbers, I'm trying to compare the float values to determine something, and then use the integer and the floats to compute an answer which will then be printed onto a separate .txt file.

Here's a sample code I made that follows the same structure as the one I'm working on (by the way, I have looked at getf() function and arrays but I'm pretty much a bigginer, so I'm still confused about how/where to use them).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main (void)
{
    int amount, x;
    float first, second, current_value, total_positive, total_negative;
    FILE *fin = fopen("numbersin.txt", "r");
    FILE *fout = fopen("resultout.txt", "w");

    x=1;
    amount=0;
    total_positive=0;
    total_negatve=0;

    while(x=1)
    {
        fscanf(fin, "%f %f %d", &first, &second, &amount);
        if((second-first) > 0)
        {
            current_value=amount*(first+second);
            total_positive=total_positive+current_value;
            fprintf(fout, "%0.2f %0.2f %d:increase = %0.2f, total increase = %0.2f", first, second, amount, current_value, total_positive);
        }
        else if((second-first) < 0)
        {
            current_value=amount*(first+second);
            total_negative=total_negative+current_value;
            fprintf(fout, "%0.2f %0.2f %d:decrease = %0.2f, total decrease = %0.2f", first, second, amount, current_value, total_negative);
        }
        else((first==0)&&(second==0)&&(amount==0));
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
    system("notepad resultout.txt");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check that loop condition again, it's an assignment. Also, read a [`scanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to see what it returns, and use that for your loop condition instead.

Comment: `while(x=1)` ?? a good way may b `while( fscanf("%f %f %d", &first, &second, &amount) != EOF)`

Comment: @DOOM And even better would be `while (fscanf(...) == 3)`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I'm sorry, I understand what you are saying, but how could the results from my scanf be used in my loop condition to make it read the other lines?  Like, could you explain what the issue is with my code that makes it only read the first line of the file, and only print one line?

Comment: Regarding the loop, read the linked reference, especially what `fscanf` returns, and the comments made by DOOM and me. Then as for your problem, you might first want to explain what `qty` is.

Comment: Also, learn how to use a debugger! In a case such as your you should be able to figure out the problems very easily by just stepping through the code line by line to see what's happening. Hints: There's an unconditional `break` in the loop.

Comment: Ah yeah I changed that just now...accidentally kept the same name from my original code

Comment: Maybe your `fscanf()` has problems with trailing white space characters or the newline character. Please try to add a trailing white space character to your format string: `"%f %f %d "`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `while` loop to work properly, you'll need to change

```
else((first==0)&&(second==0)&&(qty==0));
    {
        break;
    }
```

into

```
 else if ((first==0)&&(second==0)&&(amount==0))
    {
        break;
    }
```

The way you have it now, `break;` is always executed for every iteration.

Comment: Is this supposed to make it read/print multiple lines from the file? Because I still got the same result even with it...

Comment: Did you also remove the semicolon at the end of `else if` line?

Comment: Ohhhhhh ok, yeah...it completely works now! :)  Thanks @downhillFromHere !  Yeah, removing the semicolon changed EVERYTHING! It works great now!